# How to show dot on particular date with red and green dot color in android

Tags: android

simpleCalendarView.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.EightFragment"
    >

  <CalendarView
      android:id="@+id/simpleCalendarView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

CalendarFragment.class

```
public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_eight, container, false);
    CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.simpleCalendarView);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month,
          int dayOfMonth) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), year + "" + month + "" + dayOfMonth, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();// TODO Auto-generated method stub
      }
    });
    return rootView;
  }
}
```

This is my given using this code I'm able to show Calendar and able apply click function but I want display red, green  on some given date I just want to know can we do with calendarView below is my expected screen please suggest me if we can do this then please suggest me how I will do it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add circular decorator in calendar dayview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37854906/how-to-add-circular-decorator-in-calendar-dayview)

Comment: @ThomasMary  but i am talking about red and green  small dots how i will apply loop so that we can set dots